# Cannot open Xcode on new computer

Tags: macbook-pro, xcode

I bought a new macbook pro (13 inch with 500GB) and it came in yesterday (April 28th, 2011).

I tried downloading Xcode and was able to download it onto my computer. However when I try to and open it, it tells me that I do not meet system requirements. I did a software update check and updated all of my software.

[image: screenshot of error]

[image: screenshot of error with console]

Why can can't I open Xcode? And what can I do to fix the problem?

Comment: What version of Xcode are you trying to open. What exact model of Macbook Pro do you have? Did you buy it at Apple? Where did you get Xcode from, The Mac Apple Store?

Comment: macbook pro -

13-inch: 2.3 GHz
2.3GHz dual-core
Intel Core i5
4GB 1333MHz
320GB 5400-rpm1
Intel HD Graphics 3000
Built-in battery (7 hours)

Comment: @Martin you sound like a jealous girlfriend ;)

Comment: i bought it from the apple store it was shipped to my house

Comment: i am an apple developer, i downloaded from the app dev center

Comment: i am trying to download xcode 4.0 (IOS)

Comment: @luca Can you post the screenshot of the error? Also, are administrator of your machine?

Comment: @Loïc I am ;-) @Luca690 this is indeed very strange, since Xcode 4 can run on older hardware than that! Please post some sshot and try to reply to Loïc's questions.

Comment: yes i am the admin and i will post a screen shot in a few hours (unfortunately i am not at my mac right now but i will post as soon as possible)

Comment: Since you're a developer, I don't think I need to be too much explanatory. Can you also check in Console.app (maybe while relaunching the install) to see if you have more information

Comment: sure, but im not sure its gonna do much because xcode downloaded "successfully". Is also didn't crash cause it never opened

Comment: ok i added a screenshot of the error.

Comment: Unsubstantiated answer, but this sounds like a bad install...

Comment: yeah thats why im re-installing it but i dont know how it could have been a bad instal if im doing it straight from apple and making no modfications, but i will see how my new instal goes (it will be done in 3 minuets)

Comment: well the re-instalation worked, but is there anyway to create a shortcut on my desktop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the crash log, it can't find the `DVTFoundation` framework that Xcode needs to run.  It seems *extremely* curious to me that Xcode is running straight off of the Desktop.  Xcode comes with an installer, which (by default) will put it and all other things inside `/Developer`.  You can change it to another folder, but even then Xcode is still within the "Applications" folder of the parent folder.  In other words, there's no way to get Xcode off by itself on the Desktop unless you copied it there or didn't install it properly.

Xcode, like a couple other Apple apps, requires a whole bunch of supporting things to run (like this `DVTFoundation` framework).  You have to leave it in the place where it was installed.  Moving it to another folder is a great way to make it not work (yes, I know this isn't ideal, but it is what it is).

To fix this, trash the Xcode.app on your Desktop and re-run the installer.

Comment: thats what i am doing right now however I opened up Xcode in the Developer to debug this and got the same error message. If I was not able to open Xcode from my desktop i would probably have gotten an error similar to "could not locate the source"

Comment: well apparently the re-instalation worked. Is there anyway to create a shortcut onto my desktop?

Comment: @Luca590 sure! Find where it installed Xcode, then right click on it and choose "Make Alias". A new thing pops up called "Xcode alias" that you can move anywhere and name it anything you want.

Answer (score 1):

Your copy of Xcode is running from your desktop folder (which should be fine) but it's not seeing a library / framework file it needs.

If you got Xcode from the app store - delete the app (and all other copies of Xcode 4 that may be on your system) and re-download it from the MAS.

If you are a paid developer - you'll want to re-run the installer to make sure everything is installed in the same folder. /Xcode4 is the default - but you should be able to let the installer install everything on your desktop and it should work, but you might have better luck leaving it in the default location. Do look for duplicates Xcode copies in case it's seeing an older framework from somewhere else on your.

Don't forget the [developer discussions](http://developer.apple.com/) where everyone uses Xcode daily.

Answer (score 1):

Confirm the location from where you are launching the XCode.app.

It has to be launched from /Developers/Application. Then only it will be able to find out all the frameworks & files.